# How do I hide only the first element of a type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="ctr-1">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="ctr-2">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS

```
.ctr-1 h3:first-child{ display:none; }
```

Both `<h3>` tags are hidden, I only want the first one hidden. How?

Comment: Your selector does not match up with your markup. Did you mean `.ctr-1`?

Comment: @BoltClock - I did - that was a typo...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a few different options:

1. Use the [`:first-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#first-of-type-pseudo) pseudo class to select the first element of type:

   ```
   .ctr-1 > h3:first-of-type {
     display: none; 
   }
   ```
2. Or use the [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#nth-of-type-pseudo) pseudo class and specify the index of the first element:

   ```
   .ctr-1 > h3:nth-of-type(0) {
     display: none; 
   }
   ```
3. If type doesn't matter, and you always want to select the first child, use the [`:first-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#nth-of-type-pseudo) pseudo class:

   ```
   .ctr-1 > h3:first-child {
     display: none; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 18):

This is what the [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)  selectors are for.

For example:

```
.ctr-1 h3:first-of-type { display:none; }
/* - Or - */
.ctr-1 h3:nth-of-type(0) { display:none; }
```

This would hide the first `h3` descendant of `.ctr-1`, regardless of its location inside the parent element.

Granted, in your specific example, the `h3` is indeed also the immediate (`>`) and first (`:first-child`) descendant of `.ctr-1` . But if this is a coincidence, you might not be able rely on it. In that case, `nth-of-type` is the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

They are both technically the `first-child`.

In your example, you could do:

```
.ctr-1 > h3:first-child { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong, `ctr` doesn't exist, and you need to tell with `>` to select the first element level in your page selector try this:

```
.ctr-1 > h3:first-child{ display:none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
.ctr-1 > h3 { display: none; }
```